# One table in a two column paper

Tags: tables

I work in a two column paper and I want to insert a table as one column.

Is there any simple command to make it?

Comment: Yes. It depends on what you mean by "a table as one column". Is that a table spanning two columns, or a table within the one column (left or right)?

Comment: @Werner it is a table with 7 columns and I want to span it into two columns (show it as one)

Comment: Then consider using the `table*` environment, rather than just `table`.